# Problem in styling a monochrome plot

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have a set of functions I have plotted them in one single figure. The following are my concerns.
1. I tried to fix the legends for this figure, but unable to do this
2. Is there any way that I can plot these functions in black with different styles. I tried using the absolute dashing function to do this, and I got what I was looking for, but the problem is I need to do this separately for all the functions and later use the show function to merge them. Are there any ways that I can automate this?

```
fixedfree = Table[Sin[(2*i - 1)/(2)*π*x2], {i, 1, bmc}]
    barmodes = Flatten[{fixedfree}];
    p9 = Plot[barmodes, {x2, 0, 1}, 
      PlotLegends -> {"Mode 1", "Mode 2", "Mode 3", "Mode 4", "Mode 5"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option [`PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) :

```
Plot[barmodes, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotTheme->"Monochrome",
  PlotLegends -> {"Mode 1", "Mode 2", "Mode 3", "Mode 4", "Mode 5"}]
```

[image]

**Update:** In version 11 (Windows 7) , *"I got the plot style but still, legends are not appearing in the plot."*

Try creating the legend separately and combine it with plot using `Legended`:

```
monochromestyles = "DefaultPlotStyle"  /. (Method /. 
     Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", Plot]);

legend = LineLegend[ monochromestyles, {"Mode 1", "Mode 2", "Mode 3", "Mode 4", 
    "Mode 5"}];

Legended[Plot[barmodes, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"], legend]
```

> same picture

**Update 2:** To place the legend above the plot:

```
legend = LineLegend[monochromestyles, {"Mode 1", "Mode 2", "Mode 3", "Mode 4", 
        "Mode 5"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];

Legended[Plot[barmodes, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
  ImageSize -> {500, 300}], Placed[ legend, Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: I got the plot style but still, legends are not appearing in the plot. I copied paste the same code

Comment: @acoustics, probably version/os issue. This works fine in version 12 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: I am using wolfram 11 in windows 7, is there any ways to resolve this without reinstalling the advanced version

Comment: @acoustics, try if the approach in the update works in your version /OS.

Comment: yes sir it is working in the current version. solved the problem

Comment: Is it possible to place the legend horizontally on the top of the plot, instead of vertical sideways? I looked at some of the posts in stack exchange related to Legend position, I tried it but did not solve my problem

Comment: @acoustics, please see update 2.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, using increasingly spaced dashing.

```
bmc = 5;
fixedfree = Table[Sin[(2*i - 1)/(2)*\[Pi]*x2], {i, 1, bmc}];
barmodes = Flatten[{fixedfree}];
customdashing[i_] := Dashing[{0, 0.001*3 i, 0.001*3 i}];
p9 = Plot[barmodes, {x2, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[Directive[Black, customdashing[i]], {i, 1, bmc}],
   PlotLegends -> {"Mode 1", "Mode 2", "Mode 3", "Mode 4", "Mode 5"}]
```

[image: monochrome]

Note the `customdashing` function.
The result isn't quite as distinctive as the `PlotTheme` answer, but it should work on any version. To customise the result, you can try changing the factor in the `customdashing` function from `3i` to some larger value like `5i`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can change the font size of the legend?

Comment: Yes, instead of `"Mode 1"` use `Style["Mode 1", FontSize->value]`